# Internet Headers Are Not Setting While Sending Mail With Inline Image (Outlook Web Add-In & Office JS)

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I have created Outlook web addin using office JS. This add-in encrypts/decrypts the mail and its attachments. The sender can encrypt the mail while sending the mail. The receiver can decrypt that encrypted mail.

- For encryption, I am using HTML body of the mail.
- When the sender adds the inline image in the email body, It will be added in body as below. When I am getting the HTML body, I am getting as below.

```
<img src="https://attachment.outlook.live.net/owa/MSA%3Awin23%40outlook.com/service.svc/s/GetAttachmentThumbnail?id=&thumbnailType=2&isc=1&token=&X-OWA-CANARY=&owa=outlook.live.com&scriptVer=20230428009.16&animation=true" 
     class="ContentPasted0 w-126 h-110" 
     originalsrc="cid:f4e15c67-85fa-4e94-8ba1-02f3c6fb13fc" 
     size="386" 
     contenttype="image/png">
```

- Above HTML body will be sent encrypted by the sender.
- When receiver tries to decrypt the mail by clicking add-in button, Whole content is decrypted. But image is showing crashed/broken in the right add-in panel of the outlook.

This the flow I have developed to send the mail encrypted.

- **Get body :** `mail_item.body.getAsync('html', function (body_get_response) {});`
- Call API to encrypt the content of the mail HTML
- `mail_item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function (get_property_response) {});` to set properties using `set("key","value")` method.
- Setting headers using `mail_item.internetHeaders.setAsync({"key":"value"}, function (set_headers_response) {});`
- `mail_item.saveAsync(function (save_mail_response) {});` to save the mail with internet headers and properties.
- `mail_item.body.setAsync(encrypted_body, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function (body_set_response) {});` to set the body.

But I came to know that, When I am adding inline image to the outlook mail body, The internet headers are not setting and `mail_item.internetHeaders.setAsync({"key":"value"}, function (set_headers_response) {});` giving below error :

```
Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'object' cannot be converted to type 'string'.
Parameter name: internetHeaders
```

So basically, I am having two issues :

1. How can I encrypt the inline images.
2. How to set internet headers when there are inline images in the body of the mail.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT
I have resolved this. I came to know that my exchange certificate was expired. I have renewed it. Now I am able to set headers. But my 2nd question is still not resolved. Thanks for response.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. By 2nd question, are you referring to the "How can I encrypt the inline images." question?

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT
Yes, That's correct. While encrypting inline image, I am getting one URL on which image is hosted. I am getting `https://attachment.outlook.live.net/owa/MSA%3Aemail%40outlook.com/service.svc/s/GetAttachmentThumbnail?id=XYZId&thumbnailType=2&isc=1&token=XYZToken&X-OWA-CANARY=HeaderValue&owa=outlook.live.com&scriptVer=20230505004.14&animation=true`. Mails are encrypting successfully, But when I am trying to decrypt those, I am getting same URL. But this time, Token has been expired & I am getting '440 Login Timed Out'.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT
I have tried to convert inline images to base64 string while encrypting, But mail body came with too lengthy content. So is there any way to get those images while decrypting messages.

Comment: Hi @Smit, we won't be able to help you directly here as encryption is not supported through any OfficeJS API.